# О глаголе "знаменовать(ся)"

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов

> И, совершенно бесспорно, благодаря ей <Святой Равноапостольной царице
>   Елене> на Святой земле были построены многие храмы, в местах, которые
>   знаменовались событиями жизни Иисуса.

Он из моей пассивной лексики, никогда не пользовалась.

А пунктуация - как? ничего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И, совершенно бесспорно, благодаря ей <Святой Равноапостольной царице Елене> на Святой земле были построены многие храмы **в тех местах, которые** знаменовались событиями жизни Иисуса.

**ЗНАМЕНОВАТЬ,**  нсв. (св. ознаменовать).  Знаменоваться.

***Знаменовать*** (что?), ***знаменоваться*** (чем?). Знаменоваться — иметь отношение к чему-либо, быть связанным чем-то, свидетельствовать о чем-то.

Мир переживает те стадии, которыми **знаменовались** все решительные моменты в истории человечества. По крайней мере эти дни **не знаменовались** ни усиленным обыском, ни усиленным режимом.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно смотреть на стиль, текст с религиозной подоплёкой, здесь возможно стилизовать под старину. В активном запасе современного русского такого слова нет, а вот устаревшее есть:

https://all_words.academic.ru/27408/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%
знаменовать--ну́ет; нсв. (св. - ознаменова́ть)
см. тж. знаменоваться что - Означать что-л., свидетельствовать о чём-л.

*Освоение космоса знаменует растущий технический прогресс человечества.
Событие, знаменующее успех.
Семнадцатый век знаменовал собой начало культурного прогресса в обработке металлов.* (Словарь многих выражений. 2014)

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/817574
ЗНАМЕНОВА́ТЬСЯ, знаменуюсь, знаменуешься, несовер., чем (книжн. устар.). Выражаться в чем-нибудь, иметь какие-нибудь признаки.
(Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.)

http://enc-dic.com/rus_orthography/Znamenovatsya-38853.html
знаменоваться
знаменов'аться, -н'уюсь, -н'уется
Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник".В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.

Пунктуация, конечно, спорна. Но ведь авторской пунктуации никто не отменял

*И(,)совершенно бесспорно, благодаря ей <Святой Равноапостольной царице Елене> на Святой земле были построены многие храмы(,) в местах, которые знаменовались событиями жизни Иисуса.*

Автор имеет право поставить первую запятую после И,отнеся союз-частицу  И к обороту "благодаря ей", хотя я бы отнесла к "совершенно бесспорно" и не поставила бы её. Не очень поняла авторскую мысль: важно, что царица Елена инициатор вообще постройки храмов или именно в этих местах.

Так что можно запятую после слова храмы не ставить, а можно выделить ярче, например с помощью присоединительного тире, правда, смысл изменится.:

И совершенно бесспорно, благодаря ей <Святой Равноапостольной царице Елене> на Святой земле были построены многие храмы -  в местах, которые знаменовались событиями жизни Иисуса.

Comment: Если уж ставить знак после слова *храмы* — то тире, а не запятую. Я так понял?

Comment: Люсенька, за тире - спасибо, запятушками этими (что у Вас в скобочках) автор дорожит, но я так и не поняла, можно ли *храмы, в местах, которые знаменовались событиями жизни Иисуса*, вот эти знаменуемые места... Примеры мне не помогли - я сама гуглила, прежде чем спросить. А текст - да, вполне с религиозной подоплёкой.

Comment: Вполне - в местах, которые знаменовались ( были отмечены) событиями...

Answer (score 1):

Знаменовать(ся) не походит, а подходит ОЗНАМЕНОВАТЬ(СЯ), -ную, -нуешь; ознаменованный; -ван, -а, -о; св. (св. знаменовать). что (чем). Книжн. 1. Сделать примечательным, памятным.

**.. в местах, которые ознаменовались событиями жизни Иисуса.**

Бесспорный вариант:

**.. в местах, которые были ознаменованы событиями жизни Иисуса.**

Answer (score 1):

В официальной идеологической риторике 20 века это слово *активно употреблялось*, хотя за её пределы не выходило по причине излишней напыщенности. Тем не менее, к стилю рассматриваемого материала употреблённое слово *подходит*: автор явно успел проникнуться этим духом.

Встречались выражения "знаменует (*собой* или просто; вариант с "собой" эквивалентен слову с возвратной частицей)" и "**о**знаменовал(о)". Что касается несовершенной формы глагола, есть выбор между вполне словарными словами "**знаменоваться**" и более громоздким "**ознаменовываться**" (без возвратной частицы оно обозначает *стороннее* действие придания событию памятного статуса). Первое означает действие непрерывное (видимо, это лучше - все подряд события жизни Христа значимы, проявлялись в чём-то и отмечались чем-то), а второе - действие, время от времени происходящее (ознаменовалось тем-то тогда-то, а потом ещё раз через какой-то промежуток времени...).

Пример из материалов 27 съезда КПСС (1986 г.): *знаменует* (без о-) встречается **пять раз**: http://soveticus5.narod.ru/85/xxviit1.htm

Comment: В материалах XXVII съезда (по ссылке) нет возвратного  “знаменоваться”, зато есть "ознаменоваться": Начало XX века **ознаменовалось** выходом на историческую арену марксистско-ленинской революционной партии.